# Serving angular app at heroku without node server.js

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I have an app that works at local computer, built with angular, node and npm. I have deployed it to Heroku and got the error that binding to port was unsuccessful. Later on, I added a server.js file, changed my start command to "node server.js" and binding to port issue was solved. However, in this case the connection to backend does not work.

Is there a way to bind to the port without being forced to create server.js file and running the app only with "ng serve" command at heroku?

my package.json for frontend

```
"preinstall": "npm install -g --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular @angular/cli@11.2.14",
"ngcc": "ngcc",
"postinstall": "npm run ngcc",
"postupdate": "npm link @angular/cli",
"ng": "ng",
"start": "node server.js",
"start:ssl": "npm version && ng serve --configuration=development --ssl true --ssl-key ./ssl/localhost.key --ssl-cert ./ssl/localhost.cert",
"start:prod": "npm version && cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4096\" ng serve --prod",
"start:prod:ssl": "npm version && cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4096\" ng serve --prod --ssl true --ssl-key ./ssl/localhost.key --ssl-cert ./ssl/localhost.cert",
"build": "npm run build:dev && cd evserverch && npm install && npm run build",
"build:prod": "npm version && cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4096\" ng build --prod --stats-json",
"build:dev": "npm version && ng build --configuration=development --stats-json",
```

my package.json for backend

```
"start": "npm version && npm run start:prod",
"bundle": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
"prestart": "npm run build:prod bundle",
"preinstall": "npm install --global webpack --save-dev webpack-cli webpack-node-externals --save-dev",
"config:batch": "ncp src/assets/configs-scp/e-Mobility-config/config_batch_server.json dist/assets/config.json",
"config:oData": "ncp src/assets/configs-scp/e-Mobility-config/config_odata_server.json dist/assets/config.json",
"config:fakerest": "ncp src/assets/configs-scp/e-Mobility-config/config_fake_rest_server.json dist/assets/config.json",
"config:ocpi": "ncp src/assets/configs-scp/e-Mobility-config/config_ocpi_server.json dist/assets/config.json",
"config:rest": "ncp src/assets/configs-scp/e-Mobility-config/config_rest_server.json dist/assets/config.json",
"config:chargebox-json": "ncp src/assets/configs-scp/e-Mobility-config/config_chargebox_json_server.json dist/assets/config.json",
"config:chargebox-soap": "ncp src/assets/configs-scp/e-Mobility-config/config_chargebox_soap_server.json dist/assets/config.json",
"start:dev": "npm version && cross-env NODE_ENV=development ts-node-dev --files --max-old-space-size=4096 -- src/start.ts",
"start:dev:debug": "npm version && cross-env NODE_ENV=development ts-node-dev --inspect --files --max-old-space-size=4096 -- src/start.ts",
"start:dev:nodemon": "npm version && nodemon --exec 'ts-node --files' src/start.ts",
"start:dev:debug:nodemon": "npm version && nodemon --exec 'ts-node --files' src/start.ts 9229",
"start:dev:prof": "npm version && cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4096\" NODE_ENV=development node -r source-map-support/register --prof -- dist/start.js",
"start:dev:doctorprof": "npm version && cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4096\" NODE_ENV=development clinic doctor -- node -r source-map-support/register dist/start.js",
"start:dev:flameprof": "npm version && cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4096\" NODE_ENV=development clinic flame -- node -r source-map-support/register dist/start.js",
"start:dev:bubbleprof": "npm version && cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4096\" NODE_ENV=development clinic bubbleprof -- node -r source-map-support/register dist/start.js",
"start:devbuild": "npm version && cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4096\" NODE_ENV=development-build node -r source-map-support/register dist/start.js",
"start:prod": "npm version && cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=4096\" NODE_ENV=production node -r source-map-support/register dist/start.js",
```

I have also two configuration files for backend and frontend. the backend folder is in frontend and called evserverch, here is server.js for frontend. There is none for backend, because backend is served as worker.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static('./dist/ev-dashboard'));
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'dist/ev- 
dashboard/'});});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Comment: Do you really want to use ng serve on a remote server..?

Comment: Does is have any disadvantages? I am not a pro in angular.

Comment: Surely your best bet is to deploy a production build of your Angular app and have Heroku redirect all requests to index.html

Comment: `ng serve` is a development server, not really fit for purpose in production.

Comment: Your build command should be something like ng build —prod for heroku. As others mentioned, ng serve is only for development.

Comment: i added my code, i have alread ng build  --prod for heroku but things get a mess with node server.js because I have to many ports at backend and frontend.